# Android: Unable to instantiate application NullPointerException

Tags: android

I've got a class that I'm using to extend application. This is the code for it:

```
package com.example.myapp

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public ArrayList<Level> remoteLevels = new ArrayList<Level>();
    public ArrayList<Level> localLevels = new ArrayList<Level>();
    public TCMSQLiteHelper sqliteHelper = new TCMSQLiteHelper(this.getApplicationContext());

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.loadRemoteLevels();
        localLevels = sqliteHelper.getAllLevels();
        if(localLevels.size()>0){
            Log.d("DEBUG","Explore Data Found");
        } else {
            Log.d("DEBUG","No Explore Data Found");
        }
    }
}
```

The manifest has the following entry

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/TCMTheme"
    android:name="MainApplication">
```

I'm getting the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.myapp.MainApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException`

What am I missing?

Comment: post your full stack trace please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you define `TCMSQLiteHelper` before initiated the class

```
public TCMSQLiteHelper sqliteHelper = new TCMSQLiteHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
                                                           ^^^
```

Try this way:

```
public TCMSQLiteHelper sqliteHelper;

...

 @Override
public void onCreate() {

...
sqliteHelper = new TCMSQLiteHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Yep. I just discovered this right as your answer came in. Thanks though!